# Checkbox Preferences and Skipping Activities

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, android-linearlayout

I have a dialog custom layout, I have included a few textviews and images, However I have a checkbox and i want to be able to make this Dialog from poping up if the user checked the checkbox on the first initial launcher of the application/activity.

I dont know exactly where to take my current code from here, Any Suggestions or corrects would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

### AreYouEnlighten

```
public class AreYouEnlighten extends Activity{

Button yes;
Button no;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";
public CheckBox dontShowAgain;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_areyouenlighten);

    dontShowAgain = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);




    final Button yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continuebutton);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click

            String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())
                checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
            return;


        }
    });


    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
    if (!skipMessage.equals("checked")) {
        // if (skipMessage !=("checked") )




    final Button no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.learnmore);
    no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click


            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:3S6PTpCyW1I"));
         List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
         if (list.size() == 0) {
          // default youtube app not present or doesn't conform to the standard we know
          // use our own activity
          i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AreYouEnlighten.class);
        //  i.putExtra("3S6PTpCyW1I", videoID);
         }
         startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

### activity_areyouenlighten.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logoheader" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@color/dialog_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Hello, World" />



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Disable This Notification" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="15dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continuebutton"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Continue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/learnmore"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Learn More" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What to do or show when the user has disabled the notification?

Comment: @ottel142 Current the only thing that happens is the checkbox gets enabled then when clicked, then my dialog still populates each time.

Comment: @ottel142 I either am trying to using this checkbox save a preference for the user so they dont see this dialog box activity. Or make this activity only launcher 1 time upon initial install.

Answer (score 0):

What's the use of your yes-Button? Right now, it only saves the current CheckBox state. You better set an OnCheckedChangeListener on your CheckBox.

If the user previously enabled the skip box, the if-clause will be executed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_areyouenlighten);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    if (settings.getBoolean("skipMessage", false) {
         // skipping message, so eg. start another activity here
         Intent in = ...
         startActivity(in);
         return;
    }

    CheckBox dontShowAgain = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    dontShowAgain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            editor.putBoolean("skipMessage", isChecked);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });


    ...

}
```

Comment: What im trying to do, When opening the app this dialog(Activity) pops up, The user then can click either of the button a or b to process to other activities (a and b), The check box is to serve the purpose of skipping this first activity and going directly to activity a. This dialog is only to be poped up on the first initial launch to allow the user to disable it, then they never see it until the next reinstall of the app